# Is it possible to call a function once the payment is done through Paypal form?

Tags: meteor, paypal

I want to run a function in the background once the payment is done through paypal.

Here is my form:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="email">
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="{{item.title}}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{{item.price}}">
                    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"         border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
                </form>
```

I followed [Paypal tutorial](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/buynow_buttons/) but they didn't show how to run a function IF the payment is done successfully.

is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a payment is finished, Paypal will send you a GET parameter. This way you can run an if statement and see if there is a GET or not and then run your function.

```
if (!empty($_GET)) {

  // Your function

}
```

Comment: read more here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/

Comment: okay, couple of questions. 1- is it called automatically? i don't need to specify or add anything in the form? 2. is it possible to put this code on the server side? to it has to be on the client? Thanks :)

Comment: Question 1: read the link i linked, it will explain to you how to set it up since you will have to send some data to paypal through a hidden form for them to verify. and question 2: Yeah its possible to put it on server side.